# changing php array to show distinct value and array of product ids

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not even sure where to start with this one, and my brain is fried right now. So I thought I'd ask for some help! Basically I'm working on an opencart site, and I'm trying to change an array so it groups product_ids into categories.

Here's the array it's spitting out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 50
            [category] => Shop by Carton
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 52
            [category] => Shop by Carton
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 53
            [category] => Shop by Carton
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 54
            [category] => Shop by Carton
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 55
            [category] => Shop by Box
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 56
            [category] => Shop by Box
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 57
            [category] => Shop by Box
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 58
            [category] => Shop by Box
        )

)
```

But here's what I'm hoping to get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category] => Shop by Carton
            [product_id] => Array 
            (
                [product_id] => 50
                [product_id] => 52
                [product_id] => 53
                [product_id] => 54
            )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category] => Shop by Box
            [product_id] => Array 
            (
                [product_id] => 55
                [product_id] => 56
                [product_id] => 57
                [product_id] => 58
            )
        )
)
```

Here's the code creating the array:

```
$data['children']           = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductChildren($this->request->get['product_id']);
                    $data['options']            = array();
                    $product_option_value_data  = array();

                    foreach ($data['children'] as $product) :

                        foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($product['product_id']) as $option) :

                            foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) :
                                $product_option_value_data = $option['name'].' '.$option_value['name'];
                            endforeach;

                            $data['options'][] = array(
                                'product_id'    => $product['product_id'],
                                'category'      => $product_option_value_data
                            );

                        endforeach;

                    endforeach;

                    echo '<pre>';print_r($data['options']);echo '</pre>';
```

If anyone can help me achieve something like what I'm after, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing

```
Array 
        (
            [product_id] => 50
            [product_id] => 52
            [product_id] => 53
            [product_id] => 54
        )
```

is not possible cause key duplicate so i change a little bit
try this code

```
$lists = [
    [
        "product_id" => 50,
        "category"   => "Shop by Carton"
    ],[
        "product_id" => 52,
        "category"   => "Shop by Carton"
    ],[
        "product_id" => 53,
        "category"   => "Shop by Carton"
    ],[
        "product_id" => 54,
        "category"   => "Shop by Carton"
    ],[
        "product_id" => 55,
        "category"   => "Shop by Box"
    ],[
        "product_id" => 56,
        "category"   => "Shop by Box"
    ],[
        "product_id" => 57,
        "category"   => "Shop by Box"
    ],[
        "product_id" => 58,
        "category"   => "Shop by Box"
    ]
];

//Define temp data
$tmps = [];

foreach ($lists as $list) {
    $cat = $list["category"];
    $pro = $list["product_id"];

    if (!isset($tmps[$cat])) {
        $tmps[$cat] = [];
    }

    //add product to temp
    $tmps[$cat][] = ["product_id" => $pro];
}

//Define output
$outputs = [];

//format data from temp
foreach ($tmps as $cat => $pros) {
    $outputs[] = [
        "category"   => $cat,
        "product_id" => $pros,
    ];
}

print_r($outputs);
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

try this sample:

```
<?php

$array[0]['product_id'] = 50;
$array[0]['category'] = 'Shop by Carton';
$array[1]['product_id'] = 52;
$array[1]['category'] = 'Shop by Carton';
$array[2]['product_id'] = 55;
$array[2]['category'] = 'Shop by Box';

$newAr = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $newAr[$value['category']]['category']=$value['category'];
    $newAr[$value['category']]['product_id'][]=$value['product_id'];
}
$newAr = array_values($newAr);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newAr);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```